# Press "See more images button" of Bing by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How could I click the button shown in this image[image]

I try to find the keyword "See more images" but find nothing, I expected to find the id of the button so I could click the button by js. After that you can press the button by javascript by following instruction

```
document.getElementById(\"button_id\").click()
```

But results of Bing do not works like that, how could I click the button by js? Should I use another solution to click the button(except of using Bing api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a quick search for cats on Bing and scrolling down until the button appeared you can see the buttons definition is:

```
<a class="btn_seemore" role="button" href="javascript:void(0);" h="ID=images.6059_3,5554.1">See more images</a>
```

As the class is `btn_seemore` and this is the only occurrence of the class on the page you can simply use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn_seemore")[0].click()
```

Or preferably (in case the button hasn't been loaded yet):

```
var b = document.getElementsByClassName("btn_seemore")[0];
if(b){
    b.click();
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can't find the element using `View page source` under the right click menu in chrome as that is the source on page load rather than after scrolling, and the button only loads after scrolling, you need to use the developer tools to see the current source after scrolling to find the text.

To find the class I used chromes Element Selector tool in the developer tools (here I've shown finding the entire element in the source but the class can be seen by hovering over the element with the element selector):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how could you find the "See more images" texts? I cannot find it by the "View page source" functions of firefox or chrome.

Comment: Using chrome i scrolled until it appeared then used the element selector in the developer tools to click on it, that makes the source viewer scroll to that point

Comment: @StereoMatching see top of edit for why you couldn't find it in View page source